# compare time intervals in R

Tags: r, date

Lets say I have dataframe consisting of 3 columns with dates:

```
index <- c("31.10.2012", "16.06.2012")
begin <- c("22.10.2012", "29.05.2012")
end <- c("24.10.2012", "17.06.2012")

index.new <- as.Date(index, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
begin.new <- as.Date(begin, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
end.new <- as.Date(end, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

data.frame(index.new, begin.new, end.new)
```

My problem: I want to select (subset) the rows, where the interval of begin and end-date is within 4 days before the index-day. This is obviously only in row no 2.

Can you help me out here?

Comment: `interval1` and `interval2` are two differences between dates (btw `interval2` is negative), one cannot contains the other... either you want to know which is longer or you want to know if the 2 first dates are in between the 2 lasts ?...

Comment: I think you mean that `interval2` contains `interval1`? It seems like you are looking for `interval1 <- seq(dates.new[2], dates.new[1], by = "day");
interval2 <- seq(dates.new[3], dates.new[4], by = "day");
all(interval1 %in% interval2)`

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by "*the interval of begin and end-date is within 4 days before the index-day*". In the second row not *all* the interval is within 4 days begore the `index.new`

Answer (score 1):

Your way to express the problem is messy, in the first case `dates.new[1]>dates.new[2]` and in the second case `dates.new[3]<dates.new[4]`. Making things proper:

```
interval1 = c(dates.new[2], dates.new[1])
interval2 = c(dates.new[3],dates.new[4])
```

If you wanna check interval2 CONTAINS interval1:

```
all.equal(findInterval(interval1, interval2),c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleas let me know if this works and if is what you want

```
library("timeDate")

index <- c("31.10.2012", "16.06.2012")
begin <- c("22.10.2012", "29.05.2012")
end <- c("24.10.2012", "17.06.2012")

index.new <- as.Date(index, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
begin.new <- as.Date(begin, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
end.new <- as.Date(end, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

data <- data.frame(index.new, begin.new, end.new)

apply(data, 1, function(x){paste(x[1]) %in% paste(timeSequence(x[2], x[3], by = "day"))})
```